# Can you configure the NestJS cache TTL per-endpoint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, nestjs

I'm currently using the NestJS caching mechanism as described in the docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching

Using this I can customise the caching of an entire module with the following:

```
CacheModule.register({
  ttl: 5, // seconds
  max: 10, // maximum number of items in cache
});
```

However, there are certain **endpoints** that I want to cache for a longer period of time than the rest. (e.g. Long running operations that don't change as often as the others)

Something similar was described here: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/695 but looks like it was closed without truly solving the whole problem.

I'm imagining something like:

```
@Cache({ ttl: 600 })
@Get()
findAll(): string[] {
  return service.longRunningOperation();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register the Cache module with a generalised ttl value for your module
Then in the controller while using the class CacheInterceptor and the CacheTTL decorator from the `'@nestjs/common'` package like below

```
@Get()
@CacheTTL(100) 
@UseInterceptors(CacheInterceptor)
findAll(): string[] {
  return service.longRunningOperation();
}
```

The value inside CacheTTL Decorator overrides the default expiration time value of cache

Answer (score 2):

Control ttl cache by decorator isn't support yet. There's a [feature request](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/2943) in github to include this in a future version.

But, you can use a more verbose approach to deal with it. Inject the cache-manager object into your controllers constructors and use the 'wrap' function on each desired route:

```js
constructor(
  @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private cacheManager
) {}

@Get()
async get(): Promise<any> {
  const customers = await this.cacheManager.wrap(
    '/customers',
    function() {
      return service.longRunningOperation()
    },
    { ttl: 600 }
  )
  return customers
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do so not by using the cacheManager.
You could use another approach, you could use utils-decorators lib (npm install --save utils-decorators) and take advantage of the AsyncMemoize decorator. Then you only need to add a decorator to you controller function:

```
import {memoizeAsync} from 'utils-decorators';

class Controller {


 @Get('endpointA')
 @memoizeAsync(60 * 60 * 1000 * 12)
 endpointA() {
 }

 @Get('endpointB')
 @memoizeAsync(60 * 60 * 1000 * 24)
 endpointB() {
 }
}
```